# How to wait for variable to not equal to null in a future builder (Flutter/Dart)?

Tags: oop, flutter, dart

I have a simple app with two dart files: main.dart and bukalapak.dart

For demonstration purposes the app only has two Future Text() widgets. Basically one Text widget gets the name of a certain html, the other widget gets the total of the same html. Don't ask why but the future builder for "name" has to be in a separate stateful widget in bukalapak.dart. My question is how can I wait until the html is not null then display the total Text widget, because I can easily just call the url again but that would be doing twice the work. I only want to have to call the http.get once.

Here is the code for main.dart:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Bukalapak bukalapak = Bukalapak();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('data'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RandomWidget(
              bukalapak: bukalapak,
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  height: 28.0,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text('Total results: ${snapshot.data}')),
                );
              },
              future: bukalapak.getTotal(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code for bukalapak.dart:

```
class Bukalapak {
  var html;

  Future<dynamic> getTotal() async {
    // wait until html != null, then perform this
    var a = html.querySelectorAll(
        '#display_product_search > div.product-pagination-wrapper > div.pagination > span.last-page');
    dynamic total = int.parse(a[0].text) * 50;
    total = '$total'.replaceAllMapped(
        new RegExp(r'(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))'), (Match m) => '${m[1]},');
    return total;
  }

  Future<dynamic> getName() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://www.bukalapak.com/products/s?from=omnisearch&from_keyword_history=false&page=0&search%5Bkeywords%5D=paper&search_source=omnisearch_organic&source=navbar&utf8=✓');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      html = parse(data);

      var nameElement = html.querySelector(
          'li.col-12--2 > div.product-card > article > div.product-media > a');
      String title = nameElement.attributes['title'];
      return title;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Bukalapak error: statusCode= ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }
}

class RandomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  RandomWidget({this.bukalapak});
  final Bukalapak bukalapak;
  @override
  _TextState createState() => _TextState();
}

class _TextState extends State<RandomWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          height: 28.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
          child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text('Name results: ${snapshot.data}')),
        );
      },
      future: widget.bukalapak.getName(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass any function which notify parent widget to build future.

Following code will help you more:

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  Bukalapak bukalapak = Bukalapak();
  Widget first;
  bool isBuild = false;
  nowbuildtotal() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 1));
    setState(() {
      isBuild = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    first = RandomWidget(
      bukalapak: bukalapak,
      buildnow: nowbuildtotal,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('data'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            first,
            isBuild
                ? FutureBuilder(
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      return Container(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        height: 28.0,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                        child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text('Total results: ${snapshot.data}')),
                      );
                    },
                    future: bukalapak.getTotal(),
                  )
                : Container()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  RandomWidget({this.bukalapak, this.buildnow});
  final Bukalapak bukalapak;
  final Function buildnow;
  @override
  _TextState createState() => _TextState();
}

class _TextState extends State<RandomWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          widget.buildnow();
        }
        return Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          height: 28.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
          child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text('Name results: ${snapshot.data}')),
        );
      },
      future: widget.bukalapak.getName(),
    );
  }
}

class Bukalapak {
  var html;

  Future<dynamic> getTotal() async {
    // wait until html != null, then perform this
    var a = await html.querySelectorAll(
        '#display_product_search > div.product-pagination-wrapper > div.pagination > span.last-page');
    dynamic total = int.parse(a[0].text) * 50;
    total = '$total'.replaceAllMapped(
        new RegExp(r'(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))'), (Match m) => '${m[1]},');
    return total;
  }

  Future<dynamic> getName() async {
    print("object");
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://www.bukalapak.com/products/s?from=omnisearch&from_keyword_history=false&page=0&search%5Bkeywords%5D=paper&search_source=omnisearch_organic&source=navbar&utf8=✓');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      html = parse(data);

      var nameElement = html.querySelector(
          'li.col-12--2 > div.product-card > article > div.product-media > a');
      String title = nameElement.attributes['title'];
      return title;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Bukalapak error: statusCode= ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked, but when I printed some test whenever the getTotal() and getName() method is called, the print doesn't stop, that means the program is calling the getTotal() and getName() method over and over again. Is there any way to stop this?